# Слияние веток в git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Есть вот такая ситуация:

```
* f3aab20
*   9ba2632
|\
| *   45b8522
| |\
| | *   884c237
| | |\  
| * | \   812330f
| |\ \ \
| | |/ /
| | | /
| | |/
| |/|
| * | e4ea9e0 <-- 
| * | 418b593
| * | e2c2555
| * | fcc859b
| * | 4926873
* | | 8d0641f <-- 
| |/
|/|
```

Есть два changeset (`8d0641f` и `e4ea9e0`), которые когда-то были HEAD разных веток. Их очень неудачно слили и надо слить заново, заменив результатом их слияния то, что уже лежит на уделенном сервере.

Comment: так они же уже слиты. кстати, текстовую информацию (`git log --graph --format="%h %an"`) лучше вставлять в виде текста.

Comment: боюсь нет бранча `8b0641f`

Comment: `8d0641f` - это не бранч. это changeset. changeset-ы не изменяемы. результатом мержа двух changeset-ов всегда является новый, 3-й changeset - `884c237` на вашей картинке. в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: @PashaPash, есть два как вы говорите changeset'а которые когда-то были HEAD'ами разных веток. Их очень хреново слили и надо слить заново заменив результатом их слияния то, что уже лежит на уделенном сервере.

Comment: @ИгорьФинагин отредактируйте вопрос и впишите туда содержимое своего комментария :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать временную ветку для `e4ea9e0` (чтобы не было detached head) и затем сливать как обычно.

```
git checkout -b tmp_branch e4ea9e0
git merge 8d0641f
```